# Is it possible to have a completely portable PHP dev environment?

Tags: php, codeigniter, portability

I really want to setup a portable php environment.  I would need to use CodeIgniter, WAMP or XAMPP with MySQL and carry any projects with me between my computers/laptops.  All of this would need to be on a USB flash drive with an editor.

Is this even remotely possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like USbWebserver

http://www.usbwebserver.net

I use version 7.0 which had an SMTP option. I see they are up to 8.0 but the docs dont show the SMTP , which was quite handy.

Comment: That is very useful!  Clicking around there I noticed that they seem to make portable versions of WAMP http://www.pendriveapps.com/uniform-server-wamp-portable-website-server-package/ and XAMPP http://www.pendriveapps.com/xampp-portable-web-server/.  Is there any reason not to use those?  

Is usbwebserver a better choice?  I'm a new php dev and I'm trying to get started and being able to practice anywhere I go helps.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are just trying to learn PHP I would just stick with a basic LAMP stack. There are so many resoures out there and help available its crazy. Dont focus on the other stuff, get the syntax down, lean your variable scope etc etc. You didnt mention if you are new to programming in general or not.

Comment: Been developing .NET for about 6 years.  Looking for something new to play with for my website development.  Thank you for the info!

Comment: Oh is there a portable lamp stack?  I'm searching but turning up with nothing that looks like what I need.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try run server as virtual machine 
try this http://www.turnkeylinux.org/lamp